# How can I compare 2 words and count the strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody please help me with my code to compare 2 words and then count the string difference? Now my code is generating a wrong difference count. It seems like it is counting too much. I checked if my variable is correct and it was.

```
def difference(word_one, word_two):
    count = 0
    for letter in range(6):
        if word_one[letter] == word_two[letter]:
            count += 1
            print(letter, "letter is right.")
            return count
```

Update for my code but still some how not working. some time when I count the correct letter they don't match up like this.

`BETTER
Password incorrect
5/6 correct
BASHER`

```
def correct_letter(word_one, word_one):
    count = 0
    for letter in range(6):
        if word_one[letter] != word_two[letter]:
            count += 1
    print(letter, "out of 6 letter is right.")
    return count
```

Comment: the sample output does not match the print statement in your revised code.

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion:

```
def difference(word_one, word_two):
    return sum(l1 != l2 for l1, l2 in zip(word_one, word_two))
```

This has the advantage of not requiring `word_one` and `word_two` be of the same length, as well as any efficiency gains you might get from `zip` and `sum`.

You should of course use

```
def overlap(word_one, word_two):
    return sum(l1 == l2 for l1, l2 in zip(word_one, word_two))
```

if you want to find the similarities between two strings rather than the difference

Answer (score -1):

```
def strcmp(word_one, word_two):
    count = 0
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(word_one) and j < len(word_two):
        if word_one[i] != word_two[j]:
            count += 1
        i += 1
        j += 1

    while i < len(word_one):
        count += 1
        i += 1

    while j < len(word_two):
        count += 1
        j += 1

    return count
```